# VS Android can't find resource

Tags: android, visual-studio, android-resources

I am kinda new to this and I can't find how to solve this problem. I want to use a custom control found here: https://github.com/amccorma/xamarin-amccorma/tree/master/Forms.DropDown

After putting all files into my own project It's telling me it can't find a resource

Error:

> Severity Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error       No resource found that matches the given name (at 'style' with value '@style/spinner_style').   xx.Droid    C:\Users\xx\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\xx\xx\xx.Droid\Resources\layout\spinner.xml   2

Inside the layour folder in the resources there's a spinner.xml file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:id="@+id/Lspinner"
android:paddingLeft="5dp">
  <LinearLayout
  android:id="@+id/parentLayoutSpinner"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:showDividers="none">
<xx.Droid.CustomRenderers.DDPicker.MyAppCompatSpinner xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/spinner2"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:contextClickable="false"
    style="@style/spinner_style" />
```

**EDIT:** After removing .droid/obj and cleaning + rebuilding the solution there is no entry in the Resource.Designer.cs file.

**OLD:**
I have added the style to my Resource.Designer.cs file without success.

```
// aapt resource value: 0x7f0a0174
public const int spinner_style = 2131362164;
```

It says it's auto-generated but I can't seem to let it re-generate the file. If I remove it's contents other classes that depend on the file won't let me build the solution again.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the style you need in the example here: https://github.com/amccorma/xamarin-amccorma/blob/master/Forms.DropDown/DropDown.Droid/Resources/values/styles.xml

```
<style name="spinner_style">
  <item name="android:layout_margin">1dp</item>
  <item name="android:paddingLeft">1dp</item>
  <item name="android:paddingRight">1dp</item>
  <item name="android:paddingTop">1dp</item>
  <item name="android:paddingBottom">1dp</item>
  <item name="android:popupBackground">#FFFFFF</item>
</style>
```

to use a style, you should add it in the style file,
in your android project in `/Resources/values/styles.xml` file